# How to update session automatically using spring boot and redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, redis

I am using Spring boot and redis for user session management. When the user logs in, the session dies after a certain period of time.
I want the session duration to be updated as long as the user performs an operation. How can I do this?

In the doFilterInternal method in the JwtRequestFilter class, does it make sense to refresh the session if successful? It works when I do it this way, but is it the right method?

```
   @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain
        ) throws ServletException, IOException {
                //another codes
                sessionManager.setSession(username, jwtToken);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

  @Override
    public void setSession(String username, String token) {
        String key = "SESSION:" + username;
   
        redisService.setValue(key, token);
    }
```

Comment: You should do it at the place in your code where your session is validated and the interaction with redis happens. If your `JwtRequestFilter` does that and it works, it should be good.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have attached a sample code fragment of the part I use.